# Using 1:1 Transformer for High Side Switching

Tags: transformer, switch-mode-power-supply, gate-driving

I'm working on a 2-sw Forward Converter with isolated input and output. The design is complete on paper, but I still have a problem in my head: High side switching.

The question is, can I drive the high-side switch with a 1:1 gate driver transformer while driving the low-side switch from directly the PWM output of the IC (UC2843 or UC3843)? Is there a limitation or possible problem on this?

I'm asking this, because we have a 1:1 gate driver transformer in our warehouse and we want to use it instead of selecting a 1:1:1 one or a high-side driver IC.

Comment: As an aside, consider also [bootstrap gate driver](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/58858/7036) for high side.

Comment: Thanks, we do; but my first priority is using the 1:1 gate driver transformer that we have in our warehouse. If this is not possible, I'll go for a driver IC or 1:1:1 transformer.

Comment: If you go for transformer, make sure you wind for very low leakage inductance.